# Reset button on a changeable image document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm still in the basics of javascript coding, but in a class I was asked to set four buttons to four different javascript commands, I got three to work but not the last one, what am I doing wrong. I believe there are other ways to command it to reset but I was hoping for a way to do it via `document.getElementById`.

Also if possible is there a way to make the height grow button keep expanding besides just once? any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
<body>

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
});       

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});     

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0.2;
});   

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").reset = "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Incremental increase in height:

> ```
> var height = box.offsetHeight;
> var growth = height + 250;
> box.style.height = growth + 'px';
> ```

Reset page:

> ```
> box.reset = location.reload();
> ```

I also used a var for `box`

> ```
> var box = document.getElementById('box);
> ```

#### SNIPPET

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");


document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var height = box.offsetHeight;
    var growth = height + 250;
    box.style.height = growth + 'px';

});
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function() {

  box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function() {

  box.style.opacity = 0.2;
});
document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function() {

  box.reset = location.reload();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4" type='reset'>Reset</button>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```